# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous>

Tags: php, json, ajax

I had look to the similar question and its doesn't solve my problem 
I want to create file multiple  upload system  **with  progressbar** using php
and i have this error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) 
     at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous>
```

my code is

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$state="white";
$count=0;
if(isset($_GET["state"])){
$state=$_GET["state"];
$count=$_GET["count"];
}
?>
<html >
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="keywords" content="كتابك القريب,أدهم شرقاوي,روايات, كتب pdf,تحميل كتب,كتب دراسية,pdf,books">
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="ieyWI-BKgki1_LGBMFqdFYkGyEeHlMSEAodDuxKcN7A" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="controls.css">
   <!--

   -->
   <style>
    .bar
    {
    position: absolute;
    height: 15px;
    background-color:  rgb(27, 26, 26);
    box-shadow:inset  1px 1px 1px 1px #fff5;
    width: 80%;
    bottom: 45px;
    border-radius:15px ; 

    }
    .pbar
    {
    position: absolute;
    height: 15px;
    background-color:#941ab4;
    width: 0;
    border-radius:15px ; 
    }

   </style>

    <title>كتابك القريب</title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>

   <script>
       var state= <?php echo '"' .$state.'"' ; ?>;
       var Vcount= <?php echo $count; ?>;

        if (state=="succsses") {$(document).ready(function() { $(".succsses").css("display","block");});  }


   </script>
   <script>
       var state= <?php echo '"' .$state.'"' ; ?>;

       if (state=="error") { $(document).ready(function() { $(".error").css("display","block"); }); }


   </script>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".x").click(function() {

            $(".succsses").css("display","none");

             });
        });


        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".x").click(function() {

            $(".error").css("display","none");

             });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="succsses" id="succsses" >
    <p><?php  if ($state=="succsses") { echo"تم تحميل  ($count) ملفات بنجاح" ;}?></p>
    <span class="x">x</span>
    </div>
    <div class="error" id="error" >
    <p><?php  if ($state=="error") { echo"فشل التحميل " ;}?></p>
    <span class="x">x</span>
    </div>

    <div class="login-form">
        <img src="https://yourclosebook.com/res/logos/ryhan.png" alt="" class="ava">
        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="frm">
            <input type="email" name="email" id="" placeholder="email (اختياري)">



                <input type="file" name="file[]" id="costum-file" accept="application/pdf,application/msword,.docx" multiple >


            <input type="submit" value="تحميل" id="upload">


        </form>
        <div class="bar">
               <span class="pbar" id="pb"></span>  <span class="ptext " id="pt"></span>

           </div>
        <P> (*.pdf,*.docx,*.doc,*.ppt,*pptx)يمكنكم تحميل ملفات من الصيغ المدرجة جانبا</P>
        <h3 id="friend"> <a href="https://www.yourclosebook.com" target="_blank"  >  كتابك القريب !</a> صديقك المقرب</h3>
    </div>
    <style>


    </style>

        <script src="upload.js"></script>
        <script>
            document.getElementById('upload').addEventListener('click',function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var f = document.getElementById('costum-file');
                var pb = document.getElementById('pb');
                var pt = document.getElementById('pt');
                app.uploader({
                files:f,
                porgressBar:pb,
                porgressText:pt,
                processor:'upload.php',
                    finished:function(data){


                    },
                    error:function(){


                    }
                });

            });

        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**uploade.php**

```
<?php
require_once("conn.php");
header("Content-Type:application/json");
$err="";
$UPLOADED=NULL;
$count=0;
$i=0;
$succeded=[];
$faild=[];
for ($i; $i <count($_FILES['file']['name']) ; $i++) { 
    $target_path="uploads/";
    $file=$_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
    $file_temp=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $fileSize   =$_FILES['file']['size'][$i];
    $fileError  =$_FILES['file']['error'][$i];
    $fileType   =$_FILES['file']['type'][$i];
    $fileEXT    =explode('.',$file);
      $fileRealExt=strtolower(end($fileEXT));
    $target_path= $target_path.$file;

    $allowed    =array('pdf','doc','docx');
    if (!empty($file))  {
        if (in_array($fileRealExt,$allowed)) {
            if ($fileError===0) {
                $helpTimes=1;
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $email= $db->real_escape_string($email);
        $file= $db->real_escape_string($file);
        $UPLOADED=move_uploaded_file($file_temp,$target_path);

        if ($UPLOADED) {

            $insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO user_uploads(email,filepath,upload_time,help_times) VALUES('".$email."','".$file."',NOW(),'".$helpTimes."')");

            $count=$i+1;
            $succeded=array(
                'name'=>$name,
                'file'=>$file 

            );


        }else{
            $faild= array('name' => $name);

             echo header("Location:index.php?state=error&error=failedUpload");
        }

            }else{
                $err= "حدث خطأ غير متوقع";
                 echo header("Location:index.php?state=error&error=failedUpload");
            }
        }else{
             echo header("Location:index.php?state=error&error=notAcceptedFileFormat");
        }

    }else{
        $err=" يجب اختيار ملف واحد على الاقل";
         echo header("Location:index.php?state=error&error=empty");
    }     

  //  --------------------
  if (!empty($_POST['ajax'])) {
     echo json_encode(array(
        'succeded'=> $succeded,
        'faild'=>$faild
     ));
  }

}
echo $err;
if ($count>0) {
    //index.php
  echo  header("Location:index.php?state=succsses&count=$count");
    if (!empty($_POST['email'])) {

          $email=$_POST['email'];

          $from = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
          $from .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
          $from .= 'From: YOUR CLOSE BOOK TEAM <contact@yourclosebook.com>' . "\r\n";
          $s=" رسالة شكر";
          $messagge="<H1>باسمنا نحن فريق موقع كتابك القريب نقد لكم فائق الشكر لاجل مساعدتنا بتقديم كتبكم الثمينة</H1>";
         $mail= mail($email,$s,$messagge,$from);
          if (!$mail) {
             echo"email sending error";
          }
          else{
              echo"check your email";
          }
    }
}else{
   echo header("Location:index.php?state=error");
}
```

**upload.js**

```
var app=app ||{};
(function(o){
"use strict";
var ajax,getFormData,setProgress;


ajax =function (data) 
{
   var  xhr= new XMLHttpRequest(),uploaded;
   xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange',function()
   {
        //readyState===4 => done   
        if (this.readyState===4) 
        {
                /*
                status===200=>  ok*/


            if (this.status===200)
            {
                        uploaded= JSON.parse(this.response);
                        if (typeof o.options.finished==='function') 
                        {
                            o.options.finished(uploaded);
                        }     
            }
            else
            {
                        if (typeof o.options.error==='function') 
                        {
                            o.options.error();
                        }
            }   



        }
   });
   xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',function(event)
   {
    var percent;//%
    if (event.lengthComputable===true)

    {
        percent= Math.round((event.loaded/event.total)/100);
        setProgress(percent);
    }
   });
   xhr.open('post',o.options.processor);
   xhr.send(data);
};
getFormData =function (source) {
   var data = new FormData(),i;
   for ( i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
      data.append('costum-file[]',source[i]);

   }
   data.append('ajax',true);
   return data;   
};
setProgress =function (value) {
    if (o.options.porgressBar !== undefined) {
        o.options.porgressBar.style.width=value?value+'%':0;
    }
};
o.uploader=function (options) {
    o.options=options;
    if (o.options.files!==undefined) {
        ajax(getFormData(o.options.files.files));
    }

}
}(app));
```

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look at what the response contains.

Comment: This question can't be properly answered without the info @Sammitch is referring to. The problem is the data you're getting isn't JSON.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with your code:

In your main file you have an email element but in your upload.js file you are not adding it to your FormDara object. So in your uploade.php file you don't have access to it and `$email=$_POST['email'];` will throw an error

In your upload.js you are naming your file objects `costum-file` fun in your upload.php you are looking for file objects with the name of file. These two should have same name.

`echo header("Location:index.php");` is incorrect and you should only use `header("Location:index.php");`

If you are calling upload.php file via ajax request then you can not do php redirect(`header("Location:index.php");`). What you should do is to return some json response and then pars it in your main file JavaScript and show relevant messages(Error or success)

So to sum them up what you need to change to fix the error you are getting is(I'm just highlighting the changes and not the whole code):

**main(index.php?) file**

You need to provide an id for the email element:

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email (اختياري)">
```

You need to add this email element to your JavaScript call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('upload').addEventListener('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var f = document.getElementById('costum-file');
    var pb = document.getElementById('pb');
    var pt = document.getElementById('pt');
    var eml = document.getElementById('email');
    app.uploader({
    files:f,
    porgressBar:pb,
    porgressText:pt,
    email:eml,
    processor:'upload.php',
        finished:function(data){
        },
        error:function(){
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**upload.js**
You need to change the file element to `file` and also add the email element in the FormData object

```
getFormData =function (source) {
    var data = new FormData(), i;
    for ( i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
        data.append('file[]',source[i]);
    }
    data.append('email', o.options.email.value);
    data.append('ajax', true);
    return data;
};
```

And finally in your upload.php file change all the `echo header("Location:index.php")` instances with a json encoded string like what you have here:

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'succeded'=> $succeded,
    'faild'=>$faild
));
```

With proper response which then you can parse in your index.php file.

Please give it a try and see if it fixes your issue.

Comment: i made the changes but still dosen't work its giving  another error

Comment: @MrDamas Can you please elaborate on what error are you getting? I tested this code on my local machine and it works. I mean the uploading works, but the progress bar does not which that's another issue for it's own. So if you get an error and can't upload the files, what error are you getting?